# Neo4j /Ruby on Rails - issue with association being duplicated

Tags: neo4j, associations

Just started using neo4j on ruby on rails and i have some very simple model with one association, to keep it simple one to one. When creating one entry that suppose to create one association, when i check two associations are created.
 [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIL9K.png)

First Model:

> class Genre 
>     include Neo4j::ActiveNode
>     property :description, type: String
>     has_one :in, :book, type: :book_on
>   end

Second model:

> class Book 
>     include Neo4j::ActiveNode
>     property :title, type: String
>     has_one :out, :genre, type: :book_on
>   end

gem neo4j version 6.1.8
neo4j server running on separate VM, version 2.3.2

Anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: Can you share the code for how you created the association?  I saw somebody ask something like this, but we weren't able to get to the bottom of it

Comment: yes of course.book was added with genre selected in this form section:   `<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre %><br>
    <%= f.select :genre, options_from_collection_for_select(Genre.all, :id, :description, @book.genre.try(:id)) %>
  </div>` and i had in book controller  `def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :genre)
    end`

Comment: The controller code would be useful to.  Could you maybe publish this as a public repo so that I could clone it and try it out?  Thanks!

Comment: i added this small app to [github](https://github.com/ardelos/crowd_creative)

Comment: Looks like this is a bug that cropped up in 6.0.2.  Looking for a fix now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that I've fixed this bug in the gem.  Could you try this in your `Gemfile`?

```
gem 'neo4j', github: 'neo4jrb/neo4j', branch: '6.1.x'
```

If that works for you I'll release a patch version of the 6.1.x line (also 6.0.x because the bug first occurred in 6.0.2)

Comment: this is perfect, worked like a charm. thanks so much for quick reply and solution. glad i do not need to do graph traversal in sql.

Comment: Glad that it helped!  This is now released as `6.0.7`, `6.1.9`, and '7.0.0.rc.2`.  If you have any other Neo4j.rb questions we generally hang out on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j).  The [public Neo4j Slack group](http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/) is also useful